# When a template in an xsl file overlaps with a template in an included xsl file, the included xsl would not add the needed content

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I generate various XML files and use them as test cases for a program of mine.
I use XSLT to generate more complex test cases from basic ones to avoid duplication of the XML content. The `xsl` files include other `xsl` files to add some XML content to an existing test case.

I have a problem: when a template in `xsl` file overlaps with a template in an included `xsl` file, the included template would not add the needed content.

`Hello.xml`:

```
<EBC>
  <Positionen>
    <Position>
      <ArtikelNr>HelloWorldProductRef</ArtikelNr> 
      <HerstNr>Hello world! (ProductName)</HerstNr>
    </Position>
  </Positionen>
</EBC>
```

`Hello.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Hello.xml')/*" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`1_product_in_1_cat.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:include href="Hello.xsl" />
  <xsl:template match="Position/*[last()]" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <WWSWGNr>167000</WWSWGNr><WWSWGName_de>Mobotix IP Kameras</WWSWGName_de>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`1prod_2img_1cat.xsl`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:include href="1_product_in_1_cat.xsl" />
  <xsl:template match="Position/*[last()]" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <Bilder>
      <Bild>12011085_grob_102.jpg</Bild>
      <Bild>12011085_090.jpg</Bild>
    </Bilder>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of `Hello.xsl` and the output of `1_product_in_1_cat.xsl` is correct and I do not want to change it. The output of `1prod_2img_1cat.xsl` is not what I wanted.

The actual output is

```
<EBC>
  <Positionen>
    <Position>
      <ArtikelNr>HelloWorldProductRef</ArtikelNr>
      <HerstNr>Hello world! (ProductName)</HerstNr>
      <Bilder>
        <Bild>12011085_grob_102.jpg</Bild>
        <Bild>12011085_090.jpg</Bild>
      </Bilder>
    </Position>
  </Positionen>
</EBC>
```

The expected output is

```
<EBC>
  <Positionen>
    <Position>
      <ArtikelNr>HelloWorldProductRef</ArtikelNr>
      <HerstNr>Hello world! (ProductName)</HerstNr>
      <WWSWGNr>167000</WWSWGNr><WWSWGName_de>Mobotix IP Kameras</WWSWGName_de>
      <Bilder>
        <Bild>12011085_grob_102.jpg</Bild>
        <Bild>12011085_090.jpg</Bild>
      </Bilder>
    </Position>
  </Positionen>
</EBC>
```

I do not want the `1prod_2img_1cat.xsl` to know much about the tag names and structure of `Hello.xml` and other files. Is it possible to achieve the expected result?

Please note that the output of `Hello.xsl` and `1_product_in_1_cat.xsl` must stay the same, because they are used elsewhere.

By the way, I pass a dummy empty `xml` file on the input of my `xsl` files, so the actual input is defined by `document()` function.

Comment: Not sure why you expected it to work the way you had it. For future reference, when templates are applied to a node, only _one_ template is chosen as the "winner", not all applicable templates.

Comment: @JLRishe, thank you for your comment. I suspected, it would work so, just did not know how to make it work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use `xsl:import` instead of `xsl:include` and then replace

```
  <xsl:template match="Position/*[last()]" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <Bilder>
      <Bild>12011085_grob_102.jpg</Bild>
      <Bild>12011085_090.jpg</Bild>
    </Bilder>
  </xsl:template>
```

with

```
  <xsl:template match="Position/*[last()]" xml:space="preserve">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
    <Bilder>
      <Bild>12011085_grob_102.jpg</Bild>
      <Bild>12011085_090.jpg</Bild>
    </Bilder>
  </xsl:template>
```